# How can I show hidden files/folders in Finder

Tags: macos, finder

How can I see the hidden files in Finder?

For instance, if I have a file named: `.something`  is is not listed.

Right now I have to open the terminal and type `ls -la`.

Comment: You can use [this keyboard shortcut](http://superuser.com/questions/237275/how-to-show-specific-hidden-file-in-file-browser-dialog-mac-os-x). It works for me on Lion, though YMMV. It's especially handy for "Open File..." dialogs produced by applications like browsers because I've found these do not observe the `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles True` flag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open a Terminal and enter:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
```

Then, relaunch Finder by typing:

```
killall Finder
```

To reverse that, just enter:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

The better way I found is using an Automator service. So I can toggle directly from Finder menu without needing to launch an App

[image: Toggling hidden files]

[Toggling Hidden Files](http://blog.vitim.us/2012/10/toggle-visibility-of-hidden-files-and.html):

- [Service](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/55515130/Vitim.us/Toggle%20hidden%20files%20%28Service%29.zip)
- [App](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/55515130/Vitim.us/Toggle%20hidden%20files.zip)

To install just unzip, double click the file, you will be asked to install it, 
just click Install and then click Done.

[image]

Control+Click or Right-Click > Open

Comment: The link doesn't work for me, and you don't explain HOW to add it to the Services Menu. Can you edit your question to include the information?

Comment: This service/app are essentially *Run AppleScript* Automator actions that wrap the `defaults` and `killall` calls in a dialog-driven ("Do you want to relaunch Finder?") workflow.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this script toggle between states:

```
# check if hidden files are visible and store result in a variable
isVisible=”$(defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles)”

# toggle visibility based on variables value
if [ "$isVisible" = FALSE ]
then
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
else
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE
fi

# force changes by restarting Finder
killall Finder
```

You can also download an Automator application which will toggle hidden file visibility here:

http://www.brooksandrus.com/downloads/show_files.zip

Comment: It doesn't work on Mavericks.

Comment: for Mavericks use com.apple.Finder instead of com.apple.finder

Comment: It doesn't work too. Something wrong on `if` section.

Comment: With Mavericks, the default value is apparently `0`; `0` and `1` work as values as well as `TRUE`, `true`, `FALSE`, `false`, `yes`, and `no`. So it is indeed the condition in the `if` statement that is the problem here. I'd rather use `case` here for the multiple possible values.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create alias for this to something that you can remember. Just add the following into your .bash_login:

```
alias show_hidden_files='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE && killall Finder';

alias hide_hidden_files='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE && killall Finder';
```

Answer (score 0):

Save this applescript into a service to make it available from the Finder menu.  It will allow you to toggle hidden files on or off and when you relaunch Finder it will reopen to the directory you were previously in:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set windowTargets to target of Finder windows
    quit
end tell

set OnOff to do shell script "defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles"
    if OnOff = "NO" or OnOff = "OFF" then
        set OnOffCommand to "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles ON"
    else
        set OnOffCommand to "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles OFF"
    end if

    do shell script OnOffCommand
    delay 1

    tell application "Finder" to launch
    tell application "Finder"

    repeat with aTarget in windowTargets
        make new Finder window at aTarget
    end repeat
end tell
```