# In Snow Leopard, how do I make hidden directories visible?

Tags: macos, ipod

I’ve got some folders that I copied from a friend’s old iPod. (They’re the `F00`, `F01` folders that the old iPod used to store music files).

On my Mac (running Snow Leopard), they’re hidden in the Finder, and invisible to Python’s `glob` module.

I’d like to stop them being hidden, permanently. I know I can make the Finder show hidden files (see [How can I show hidden files/folders in Finder](https://superuser.com/questions/53383/)), but I’d like to make the directories themselves be not hidden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Terminal.app:

```
SetFile -a v F00 F01
```

You can see the raw attribute data with:

```
xattr -l F00 F01
```

`SetFile` is in the Developer Tools package.  If you can't install that, you can try to manipulate the extended attributes directly using xattr.

A directory whose only extended attribute is invisibility looks like this:

```
com.apple.FinderInfo:
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........@.......|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
```

If your xattr output matches that, you should be safe just deleting the com.apple.FinderInfo attribute:

```
xattr -d com.apple.FinderInfo F00
```

If it doesn't exactly match, you should be safe rewriting the attribute after subtracting that '4' from that position:

```
mac% xattr -l F00
com.apple.FinderInfo:
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 10 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........@.......|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020
mac% xattr -wx com.apple.FinderInfo 0000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 F00
mac% xattr -l chgfndrcom.apple.FinderInfo:
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Note that SetFile is part of the Developer Tools, so you’ll need to have those installed.

Comment: Oh, good call on the Developer Tools.

Comment: I was wondering how to read the long output of `xattr`, i.e. how did you know what the extended attribute looks like for an invisible dir - is there a manpage for that?

Comment: Found it [here](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Finder_Interface/finder_interface.pdf), page 13.

Answer (score 2):

Why not using chflags as SefFile comes only with Xcode?

```
chflags hidden path_to_file
chflags nohidden path_to_file
```

Comment: Nice one, good to have a non-Developer Tools option. And welcome to Superuser.