# Hidden file/folder in MacBook Pro (Mac OS X 10.6) Finder

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, finder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I show hidden files/folders in Finder](https://superuser.com/questions/53383/how-can-i-show-hidden-files-folders-in-finder)

How can I hide file/folder in Finder and roll it back easily (like windows)
and how can I tell Finder to show hidden files or not (like folder option(hide hidden file) in Windows)

I don't want a way like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/53383/show-hidden-files-folders-in-finder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [hiddenfiles](http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/developer/hiddenfiles.html) widget for dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

you might want to look at [totalFinder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com). Among other neat things (such as giving you tabs and split pane browsing) it lets you turn on hidden files in Finder.

Otherwise, open a terminal window and type

```
ls -a /path/to/your/folder
```

where /path/to/your/folder is the unix-style path to the folder you want to list. The easiest way to get this is to type *ls -a*, then drag the folder into the terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

I use [sterMachine](http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/macosx/24019) Among other things, it lets you choose to see all hidden files. To hide files, you can just stick a dot infront of them...