# Is it possible to toggle hidden files without relaunching Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, user-experience

There are several ways how to toggle hidden files - via a shell [command](https://superuser.com/questions/53383/show-hidden-files-folders-in-finder), or AppleScript, or Automator [action](http://theappleblog.com/2007/04/30/quick-tip-showhide-hidden-files/), or even a Dashboard [widget](http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/developer/hiddenfiles.html). All of them close and reopen Finder windows, which is quite annoying.

On the other hand, for the Open File dialog one can easily toggle hidden files by pressing `Command+Shift+Period`.

Is it possible to avoid relaunching Finder?

---

**Conclusion**

It is better to use [Path Finder](http://www.cocoatech.com/) instead, which allows not only to toggle hidden files without a perversion, but many other nice things. Really awesome app.

Comment: The "theoretical" part of the question kind of made this argumentative (and hence subject to be closed), unless some Apple engineer happens to be reading this. I like the rest of the question though, so I removed those words. I *guess* the answer is currently "no", as *probably* Finder reads this setting when it's started. But that's an argumentative answer, so let's hope for an answer that says "yes, ..."

Comment: Too bad. Accepting the "no" also ensures the Community user [will never poke this question](http://superuser.com/users/-1/community), to bump it onto the front page every now and then...

Comment: Ok, good point. Let's leave some hope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a solution now.

The latest release of [TotalFinder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/) (0.9.1) can toggle show/hide hidden files without Finder restart. Tested it, it works well, and removes this long-lived annoyance of the Finder. TotalFinder is free for now as it is prerelease software, but will be around $10 or $15 when it hits final.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot, because there is no way to notify the Finder (or any process for that matter) that its preferences file has been modified behind its back.

Comment: That assumes the only way to make Finder show hidden files is by hacking its preferences. (Which *probably* is true indeed.)

Comment: There's no need for assumption when the facts are right there.

Comment: Then point us to those facts, please...

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question here: [Apple Script - Reopen Closed Finder Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/675386/apple-script-reopen-closed-finder-windows)

The posted script by [adayzdone](https://superuser.com/users/126010/adayzdone) may be what your looking for.  It still has to relaunch Finder but when it relaunches, it returns the the same windows in the same directory you were in when they closed.

```
tell application "Finder"
   set windowTargets to target of Finder windows
    quit
end tell

set OnOff to do shell script "defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles"
    if OnOff = "NO" or OnOff = "OFF" then
        set OnOffCommand to "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles ON"
    else
        set OnOffCommand to "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles OFF"
    end if
    do shell script OnOffCommand
    delay 1

tell application "Finder" to launch
    tell application "Finder"
    repeat with aTarget in windowTargets
        make new Finder window at aTarget
    end repeat
end tell
```

---

*copied from referenced question*