# Apple Script - Reopen Closed Finder Windows

Tags: macos, mac, finder, applescript

I have the following Applescript which toggles the show/hide hidden files and I would like to reopen the user's Finder windows which will be closed as the Finder gets relaunched.

```
tell application "Finder" to quit
set OnOff to do shell script "defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles"
if OnOff = "NO" or OnOff = "OFF" then
    set OnOffCommand to "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles ON"
else
    set OnOffCommand to "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles OFF"
end if
do shell script OnOffCommand
delay 1
tell application "Finder" to launch
tell application "Finder"
    try
        target of window 1
        make new Finder window to result
    on error
        make new Finder window to home
    end try
end tell
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work? @user495470's answer below doesn't reopen the windows, like you said.

Answer (score 1):

You might just disable closing windows when you quit Finder:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool true
```

I use this script to toggle showing hidden files:

```
do shell script "[[ $(defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles) = 1 ]] && b=false || b=true
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool $b"
tell application "Finder"
    quit
    delay 0.1 -- without this delay Finder was not made frontmost
    launch
    delay 0.5 -- without this delay there was sometimes a "connection is invalid" error
    activate -- make Finder frontmost
    reopen -- open a new default window if there are no open windows
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for the script.  It works quite well, but doesn't relaunch the Finder windows until you manually select the Finder icon in the Dock.  (at least this is how it's working for me)  Still good though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set windowTargets to target of Finder windows
    quit
end tell

set OnOff to do shell script "defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles"
if OnOff = "NO" or OnOff = "OFF" then
    set OnOffCommand to "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles ON"
else
    set OnOffCommand to "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles OFF"
end if
do shell script OnOffCommand
delay 1

tell application "Finder" to launch
tell application "Finder"
    repeat with aTarget in windowTargets
        make new Finder window at aTarget
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Hi there, sorry this just open's up a new finder window with the location of `My Mac`