# Mac, reopen finder on restart of system

Tags: macos, finder

On my windows system as I restart my old Explorer windows reopen all the Explorer windows I had the last time when I shut down, is it possible for me to do the same for my Mac Finder windows?

I am on version 10.9.5

I had a look at:
[Apple Script - Reopen Closed Finder Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/675386/apple-script-reopen-closed-finder-windows)

but that seems to use some scripting that as a noob to the Mac I really don't have a clue about (plus that question is a year old, perhaps something has changed... ), i was hoping for something where I can change a setting (like I did on Windows)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible, when you shut down (or restart) your Mac with your Finder windows still open, just check the checkbox that says "Reopen windows when logging back in". When you log back in, all of your windows that were open when shut down will re-open. Here is a picture of the checkbox, when you click Shut Down or Restart from the Apple menu (top left): [image: reopen windows when logging back in]

Comment: Works for any apps that were open, too.

Comment: Where do I find this option "Reopen windows when logging back in"? I don't know my way around the mac well...

Comment: @Ryan this option should automatically pop-up when you go to logoff, restart or shutdown your mac. Being on 10.9.5, this should automatically show

Comment: Thanks! I think something was wrong as I didnt get that option, but its working now :)

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, your other option is to go into System Prefs -> Users a& Groups. Then click on your username and on the right-hand side click on Login Items. You can then specify specific folders to open of your choosing