# How to show specific hidden file in file browser dialog - Mac OS X

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, automator

I need to use **Automator** to backup some of config files in my Mac. But I don't know how to get a hidden file in the file browser dialog. I chose **"Get Specified Finder Items"** task then click ***Add***, but the file browser didn't show the hidden files I want to select.

How can I get the hidden files I need?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Press `Cmd-Shift-.` in the file dialog to show hidden files.