# Adding a plugin Vim Folder on a MacOSX

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugins

I saw a tutorial on using VIM and I was curious how the user actually added a couple plugins without opening the content of the MACVIM app, but instead by going to the folder plugin using the command "~/.VIM" As seen here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dmv6-dguS3g&feature=player_embedded#at=70

I'm not really sure how everyone is able to do this.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`~/.vim` is not a command, but a hidden folder.

Open Terminal and enter

```
mkdir .vim
```

to create it, if it doesn't exist yet. To go there, switch to Finder and press `Cmd-Shift-G`, and enter `~/.vim`.

---

See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/53383/show-hidden-files-folders-in-finder) regarding displaying hidden files in Finder. Or you can just press `Cmd-Shift-.` in any open/save file dialog to see hidden files and folders.

---

I don't know if you need to configure Vim to use that folder, but it doesn't look like it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm curious though, how is the folder linked to the plugin support for macvim?

Comment: @Joon-Sub, it has nothing to do with MacVim. It's the default location for all the stuff you want Vim to source at startup: plugins, syntaxes, colorschemes etc. Also it's probably not a very good idea to jump directly to installing plugins or copying verbatim someone else's `.vimrc`. You should instead start in the Terminal by launching Vim's tutorial `vimtutor` a few times until you are comfortable with it and do some exercises of your own on non-critical files. Once you get the basics you'll be able to customize your environment and soon discover that you don't need that much customizing.